# Distance covered by point on the rim

Tags: geometry

Given a circular wheel that is rotating at the rate of $25$ revolutions per minute. If the radius of the wheel is $50 \space cm$, what could be the distance covered by a point on the rim in one second (Given that $\pi  = 3.1416$)

Any takes? Thanks.

Comment: Just use conversion factors. One revolution is $2\pi\times50\text{ cm}$ (why?), and there are sixty seconds in a minute...

Comment: Is the wheel rolling along the ground? Or just rotating about a fixed axle? In the first case, the distance covered depends on the initial position of the point.

Answer (score 2):

The number of revolutions per second is
$$\def\textstyle{}
25{\textstyle {\text{ rev} \over \text{ min}}}\cdot\textstyle{1\over 60}\textstyle{\text{min}\over \text{sec}  } 
={25\over 60}{\text{rev}\over\text{sec}}
={5\over12}{\text{rev}\over\text{sec}}.$$ 
The point travels  $\pi\cdot2\cdot50=100\pi {\text{ cm}\over\text{rev}}$ . So, in one second, the distance would be $$\underbrace{100\pi \textstyle {\text{ cm}\over\text{rev}}}_{\text{ dist per rev}}\cdot\underbrace{\textstyle {5\over12}\textstyle{\text{rev}\over\text{sec}}\cdot 1\text{sec}}_{ \text{number of revs.}}={125\pi\over3} \text{ cm}.$$

See TonyK's comment.   The above is for a wheel whose center remains stationary.

Comment: it would be total distance covered by a point of rim but how much distance would that be per second. Since, angle is described per second equals (Θ) = 50π/60 = 5π/6. S = r x Θ = 50cms x 5π/6 = 130.9cms.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The point travels $125\pi/3$ (which is the same as you have) centimeters per second. (In the above,    the wheel is rotating at $5/12$ revs per second, which gives the angle as $\theta={5\over 12}\cdot 2\pi= {5\pi\over6}$.)